# How to connect to a windows ethernet adaptor with WSL?

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, wsl2

On a windows10 computer I have an ethernet adaptor "Ethernet" which is assigned the IP address 192.168.200.5

[image]

Running WSL on windows I can see that this adaptor is not in `ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.192.7  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.30.207.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe6f:79f6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:6f:79:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 229921  bytes 299009834 (299.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29166  bytes 2148189 (2.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How am I able to access the ethernet adaptor "Ethernet" from within WSL?

Comment: You can't. Not even Hyper-V allows you to "passthrough" an adapter. I haven't been following whether or not WSL now allows you to bridge to one though.

Answer (score 2):

> How am I able to access the ethernet adaptor "Ethernet" from within WSL?

Mostly, you **aren't** able to access it. WSL2 is basically the same as any other virtual machine – it gets a virtual network adapter – and in the only configuration supported by WSL at the moment, it always works in routed/"NAT" mode with the host OS forwarding packets back and forth (acting as the router).

So if the *host's* (i.e. Windows) routing table directs some packets through the "Ethernet" interface, this will also apply to traffic from WSL – but that's it.

However, if you get the [September 2023 update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2023-update/) of WSL (**and** if you're already using Windows 11 22H2 "Release Preview"), you can enable the newly added `mirrored` networking mode, where WSL presents a virtual network interface for *each* of the host's interfaces, directly bridged to each. This should be similar to "Bridged" networking in VirtualBox, and should allow software on the WSL VM to choose which interface it wants to use.